# IPC between two process running on two different OS on single hypervisor virtualized machine

Tags: linux-kernel, virtual-machine, ipc, virtualization, hypervisor

IS there any known way to do Inter process communication between two operating system running on a same hardware and virtualized by XEN.

I know i can do Remote Method Invocation(RMI/RPC) to do process communication on a network, and which i can definitely do here also.

IPC can be achieved by following ways

> 1. Signals
> 2. Anonymous Pipes
> 3. Named Pipes or FIFOs
> 4. SysV Message Queues
> 5. POSIX Message Queues
> 6. SysV Shared memory
> 7. POSIX Shared memory
> 8. SysV semaphores
> 9. POSIX semaphores
> 10. FUTEX locks
> 11. File-backed and anonymous shared memory using mmap
> 12. UNIX Domain Sockets
> 13. Netlink Sockets
> 14. Network Sockets
> 15. Inotify
> 16. FUSE subsystem
> 17. D-Bus subsystem

OUt of which I think 12 to 16 can be used since which allows network and file based notification and communication protocols.

Is there a way that i can use any of the method between 1 to 10(inclusive) can be used for the IPC between two OS running on same hardware with virtualization

Answer (score 1):

First 1-10 looks like tightly sticked to ipc inside one os and does not designed to do machine-to-machine ipc. Maybe some of them can use netowrking as transport, but in this case it is better to use network itself.
If you try to find something with almost zero-conf you can use such things as vsock on kvm or hyper-v sockets on hyper-v. This is socket api that works without other network stack and using its own guid based address space. But they are not commonly used and can be problematic for usage in some cases. For example hyper-v sockets works fine only on centos-rhel, and vsock can have some troubles with machine-to-machine communication. And a good news that xen looks like supports vsock https://xenbits.xen.org/people/dvrabel/inter-domain-comms-C.pdf .